# PHP POST request equivalent to javascript one

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to write a simple PHP plugin which would fetch data from a server and display them for the user.

I have managed to access the server with the following javascript code. However when I tried to do the same using PHP (Which was my goal all along.) I get only a timeout or an error.

Could you please point out the difference / error in my PHP code in relation to the javascript one?

Working JS example:

```
    function myFunction() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'URL',
    headers: {
        'Authorization':'KEY',
        'PortalAuthorization':'KEY', 
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({"ServerName":"MAIN","List":null}),
    error: function(xhr, error){
       console.debug(xhr); 
       console.debug(error);
    },
    success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    }
 });
 }
```

Atempted PHP equivalent:

```
<?php
    function prepare_headers($headers) {
        return
        implode('', array_map(function($key, $value) {
                return "$key: $value\r\n";
            }, array_keys($headers), array_values($headers))
        );
    }
//json parsing
    $son->ServerName = "MAIN";
    $son->List = "null";
    $JS = json_encode($son);
    $len = strlen($JS);

    $headers = array('Authorization'=>"KEY",
    'PortalAuthorization'=>"KEY",
    'Content-Type' => "application/json", 'Content-Length' => $len
                    );

    $oo = prepare_headers($headers);
    $url = urldecode('URL');
    $context = stream_context_create(array( 'http' => array(       
        'method'=>"POST",
        'header'=> $oo,
        'Content' => $JS
    )));
    $result = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
?>
```

This results in warning:  failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! and subsequent Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded both caused by line `$result = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);`

I also tried to just do `'header'=> $headers` but that resulted in a different error:  failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required in `$result = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);` again

I am not familiar with PHP so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $url = urldecode('URL'); ??? Doe you literally want the string 'URL'?

Comment: whatever `'URL'` is, looks like it is not reachable from the host running your php.

Comment: @Roemer the URL is just a placeholder, in the code itself I have both URL and KEY replaced with working values.

Comment: Top. just  skip the urldecode anyway, might have something to do with that. You don;t want to decode a URL that you are gojng to use as a URL.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I am testing this on localhost using XAMPP.

Comment: suit yourself .... @pppddd

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I am not familiar with web stuff either, so my idea was to test my code locally so that I wouldn't have to upload it to the server with every iteration. I thought that running a server on my computer using XAMPP and then trying my plugin there would be equivalent to me uploading it to server and testing it there. From what you are saying it seems that the issue is caused by this approach so that the localhost cannot reach the url.